# KQL - URL Path Too Large - SPFx TaxonomyPicker (setting initial values)

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, query-string, taxonomy, spfx

I am fairly new to SPFx and am having an issue.

**Descrption**
I have a SPFx React Control (Taxonomy Picker) which allows the user to select multiple terms. These terms are then pushed to the query string (via KQL) to perform a search with PnP Search Results

**Issue**
When the user selects a lot of tags, chrome (or any browser) errors, has to do with the URL being too long

I am passing the entire IPickerTerm object (JSON.stringify) to the query string so that when I reload the page and setting the query string '?terms={IPickerTermsAsString}', I can read the query string and pass through the direct object (via JSON.parse)

**Tried**
I have tried to just capture the term path in the QS (rather than all properties, key, name, path and termset) and then using SharePoint APIs to get the term details on load, however React is rendered before my calls have completed executing..

Any ideas on what else I should try?

Comment: what about using a callback ?

Comment: Hey Mukul, 


Not sure if its my lack of knowledge with the SPFx React control, but the rendering of my webpart is done first before the callback is complete.

Do you know if there is a way to set the selected item (lets say passing through IPickerTerm) once it has rendered?


The control has these two methods that we can utilise:
initialValues
 - doesn't work setting this field as it is already rendered, async/callback doesn't work here

onChange
 - this updates my state, it changes the state but not the control value.